# Microsoft Bot Web Chat and Microsoft Teams doesnt work but the bot works on localhost

Tags: node.js, azure, heroku, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I created a Microsoft Chat bot with Luis and heroku but the bot is only working on localhost.

I Already followed the steps described on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Every step is successful and even if I am testing it on localhost with my Bot-Id and Bot-Password the application is running.

But if I try to use my bot in the Web Chat from Azure or implement it in Microsoft Teams it doesn't work.

This is the address for the heroku application:
https://movie-booking-bot.herokuapp.com/

Does anyone have an idea why it is not working? Is something wrong with my code or am I missing some configurations?

Problem Statement:

The Bot is only responding on localhost. I don´t get any message if I am testing the bot in the web chat or over Teams.

Thank you in advance for your help.

The following logs I get from heroku when I am sending a message in the web chat:

```
2019-06-29T20:12:14.084375+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api       /messages" host=movie-booking-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=4b72f187-1e7f-480b-bb77-3f68ea0842e4 fwd="13.94.244.42" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=202 bytes=117 protocol=https
2019-06-29T20:12:16.293731+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/messages" host=movie-booking-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=b2634bfe-855e-49d6-855a-93a2ce746ecb fwd="13.94.244.42" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=202 bytes=117 protocol=https
2019-06-29T20:12:16.325668+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/messages" host=movie-booking-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=550e1f4b-0cf8-4224-971e-bf007be659bc fwd="13.94.244.42" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=202 bytes=117 protocol=https
2019-06-29T20:12:16.326065+00:00 app[web.1]: The Bot State API is deprecated.  Please refer to https://aka.ms/I6swrh for details on how to replace with your own storage.
2019-06-29T20:12:16.487948+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: GET to 'https://state.botframework.com/v3/botstate/webchat/conversations/GHZx9biLjXS1vmTW2BqFUS-h/users/DUnoSSshPmV' failed: [405] Method Not Allowed
2019-06-29T20:12:16.487952+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request._callback (/app/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/ChatConnector.js:675:46)
2019-06-29T20:12:16.487954+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.self.callback (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
2019-06-29T20:12:16.487956+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-06-29T20:12:16.487958+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
2019-06-29T20:12:16.487960+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
2019-06-29T20:12:16.487961+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-06-29T20:12:16.487963+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
2019-06-29T20:12:16.487964+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
2019-06-29T20:12:16.487966+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
2019-06-29T20:12:16.487967+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
```

```js
     var builder = require('botbuilder');
     var restify = require('restify');


    var server = restify.createServer();
    server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function() {
        console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
    });

    var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({

     appId: 'ID',
        appPassword: 'PASSWORD'


    });

    server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

    var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

    var LuisAPPId= "ID";
    var LuisAPIKey ="Password";
    var LuisAPIHostName ="westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com";

    const LuiSModelURL ='https://' + LuisAPIHostName + '/luis/v2.0/apps/'     +LuisAPPId +'?subscription-key=' + LuisAPIKey;

    var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuiSModelURL);
    var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({
        recognizers: [recognizer]
    });



    bot.dialog('/', intents);

    intents.matches('Greet', (session, args, next) => {
        session.send("Hello I`am your digital cinema assitents. I can     inform you about movies or book direct one or several tickets for you.");
    });

    var movies = [
        "spider-man",
        "rampage",
        "the avengers",
        "jurassic world"
    ];


    intents.matches('ShowNowPlaying', (session, args, next) => {
        session.send("Hey this is our programm of movies which are played     :)\n\n" + movies.join("\n\n"));
    });

    intents.matches('BookTicket', [(session, args, next) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(args));

        var movieEntity = args.entities.filter(e => e.type == 'Movies');
        var NumOfTicketsEntity = args.entities.filter(e => e.type ==     'builtin.number');

        if(movieEntity.length > 0)
        {
            session.userData.movie = movieEntity[0].resolution.values[0];
        }
        else {
            delete session.userData.movie;
        }

        if(NumOfTicketsEntity.length > 0) {
            session.userData.NumOfTickets =     NumOfTicketsEntity[0].resolution.value;
        } else  {
            delete session.userData.NumOfTickets;   
        }

        if(!session.userData.movie) {
            session.beginDialog('askMovie');
        }
        else{
            next();
        }

    }, (session, args, next) => {

        if(!session.userData.NumOfTickets) {
            session.beginDialog('askNumOfTickets');
        }
        else{
            next();
        }


    }, (session, args, next) => {
        session.send("Sure, I have booked you " +     session.userData.NumOfTickets + " tickets for " + session.userData.movie + ".     Have Fun")
    }]); 

    bot.dialog('askMovie', [(session, args, next) => {
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'What movie would you like to watch?',     movies);
    }, (session, results) => {
        session.userData.movie = results.response.entity;
        session.endDialogWithResult(results);
    }]);

    bot.dialog('askNumOfTickets', [(session, args, next) => {
        builder.Prompts.number(session, 'Great! How many tickets do you would     like to have?');
    }, (session, results) => {
        session.userData.NumOfTickets = results.response;
        session.endDialogWithResult(results);
    }])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Specifically, what does "doesn't work" mean? Have you checked your server logs, e.g. via `heroku logs`? What to they say? Please read [ask].

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, run `heroku logs` to see your logs.

Comment: Okay, so we have `GET to 'https://state.botframework.com/v3/botstate/webchat/conversations/GHZx9biLjXS1vmTW2BqFUS-h/users/DUnoSSshPmV' failed: [405] Method Not Allowed`. Does [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/08/01/bot-framework-405-method-not-allowed-401-unauthorized-and-500-internal-server-error-getting-started/) help?